# I am not able to understand class <classname>(unicode): in Python?

Tags: python, oop, object

```
 class Car():  
    def __init__(self,input):  
        self.carName = input  
    def showName(self):  
        print self.carName  
 a = Car("bmw")  
 print type(a)  
 print a
```

This returns me

```
<type 'instance'>
<__main__.Car instance at 0x7f188f38de60>
```

Whereas

```
 class Car(unicode):  
    def __init__(self,input):  
        self.carName = input  
    def showName(self):  
        print self.carName  
 a = Car("bmw")  
 print type(a)  
 print a  

<class '__main__.Car'>
bmw
```

As far as I understand, print  triggers the object.**str**() method but what is the significance of unicode here ?

Answer (score 3):

The significance is that you've created a class that subclasses the built-in class `unicode`. It's hard to see why you would want to do that for a class named `Car`.

Comment: i was trying to experiment, is the `__str__` method, defined for the Unicode class ? i'm sorry, but i'm unable to locate the correct documentation for it.

Comment: @sharky: Of course `unicode` has `__str__` (and many other methods). Try `dir(u'')`.

Comment: thanks, by doing this I also came across the `__dict__` method, +1